# How to add custom css in react hook useEffect

Tags: css, reactjs, use-effect

I am new to React and I am trying to enforce font style to specific inputs and their placeholders.
This loads everything but my `CustomFontStyle`. Does anyone know what I am missing?

```
import 'styles/utilities.scss';
useEffect(() => {
        const baseFieldStyles = {
            color: '#e60000',
            font: 'normal 400 0.875em CustomFontStyle'
        };

        const myConfiguration = {
            onFieldEventHandler: {
                onFocus: tagId => {
                    setFocus(tagId);
                },
                onBlur: () => {
                    setFocus('');
                }                
            },
            expirationDatePlaceHolder: 'MM/YY',
              style: {
                  input: {
                      ...baseFieldStyles
                  },
                  '::placeholder': {
                      ...baseFieldStyles
                  },
                  span: {
                      ...baseFieldStyles,
                      'line-height': '30px'
                  }
              }
        };
    }, [
        staticData.getSection,
        shouldRenderFields
    ]);
```

**utilities.scss**

```
@import '~styles/_globals.scss';

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CustomFontStyle';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: All i see is objects being defined, which obviously nothing is going to happen. Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to working   ::placeholder ..... you have to use **opacity: 1**